# i want a linux script that will be able to compare both files and after comparing it should display something

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, diff

file 1

```
products           total 
apple               6
yam                 5
fish                6
meat                3
```

file2

```
products           total 
apple               6
yam                 7
fish                3
meat                5
```

what i want to do.
i want a script that will compare the content of the two files 
it should match the product in file1 to the one in file to and compare the total 
and when the total in file 1 is more than the one in file 2 it should display something if not it should display something else

what im expecting

```
file 1                               file 2                       the output of the script  

products           total        products           total              
apple               6            apple               6                 they are equal 
yam                 5            yam                 7                  file 2 is more
fish                6            fish                3                  file 1 is more
meat                3            meat                5                  file 2 is more
```

Comment: what js the problem with your code?

Comment: its not able to compare the total so its not displaying what im expecting it to

Comment: that does not describe the problem ... why are you asking us to guess what code you are using and guess what the displayed result might be?

Comment: @bob Please click [edit] and add your code to your question, and describe what it doesn't do which you need it to. Please do not use Add Comment (which doesn't let you format your code); please instead use [edit].

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly:

Assuming that file is delimited with tabs use a loop to store all the values of your elements and then iterate over the two loops comparing them

```bsh
prods1=() #product names in file 1
tots1=() #totals in file 1

prods2=() #product names in file 2
tots2=() #totals in file 2


#read in the stored values
while IFS=\t read -r p t; do
    prods1+=("$p")
    tots1+=("$t")
done <<< file1

while IFS=\t read -r p t; do
    prods2+=("$p")
    tots2+=("$t")
done <<< file2

output=() #will store your output

for((i=0; i<${#tots1[@]};++i)); #you can set i to 1 if you want to skip the headers
do
    #check if the values are equivalent
    if ((${tots1[i]} == ${tots2[i]}));
        output+="They are equal"

        #ADD THE REST OF THE COMPARISONS HERE
    fi
done
```

After that, the array `output` will contain your desired output and you can print it to the console or a file in any format you see fit :)